# SSIS 2014 ADO.NET connection to Oracle slow for 1 table (the rest is fine)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

We're in the middle of doing a new data warehouse roll-out using SQL Server 2014. One of my data sources is Oracle, and unfortunately the recommended Attunity component for quick data access is not available for SSIS 2014 just yet.

I've tried avoiding using OLEDB, as that requires installation of specific Oracle client tools that  have caused me a *lot* of frustration before, and with the Attunity stuff supposedly being in the works ([MS promised they'd arrive in August already](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/917247/when-will-attunity-ssis-connector-support-sql-server-2014)), I'm reluctant to go through the ordeal again.

Therefore, I'm using ADO.NET. All things considered, performance is acceptable for the time being, with the exception of 1 particular table.

This particular table in Oracle has a bunch of varchar columns, and I've come to the conclusion that it's because of the width of the selected row that this table performs particularly slow. To prove that, rather than selecting all columns as they exist in Oracle (which is the original package I created), I truncated all widths to the maximum length of the values actually stored (`CAST(column AS varchar(46)`). This reduced the time to run the same package to 17 minutes (still way below what I'd call acceptable, and it's not something I'd put in production because it'll open up a world of future pain, but it proves the width of the columns are definitely a factor).

I increased the network packet size in SQL Server, but that did not seem to help much. I have not managed to figure out a good way to alter the packet size on the ADO.NET connector for Oracle (SQL Server does have that option). I attempted to see if adding `Packet size=32000;`to the connection string for the Oracle connector, but that just threw an error, indicating it simply won't be accepted. The same applies to FetchSize.

Eventually, I came up with a compromise where I split the load into three different parts, dividing the varchar columns between these parts, and using two `MERGE JOIN` objects to well, merge the data back into a single combined dataset. Running that and doing some extrapolation leads me to think that method would have taken roughly 30 minutes to complete (but without the potential of data loss using the `CAST` solution from above). However, that's still not acceptable.

I'm currently in the process of trying some other options (not using `MERGE JOIN` but dumping into three different tables, and then merging those on the SQL Server itself, and splitting the package up into even more different loads in an attempt to further speed up the individual parts of the load), but surely there must be something easier.

Does anyone have experience with how to load data from Oracle through ADO.NET, where wide rows would cause delays? If so, are there any particular guidelines I should be aware of, or any additional tricks you might have come across that could help me reduce load time while the Attunity component is unavailable?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running the same queries against the database directly? SSIS won't help you if it's the database that's slow. Also, you don't *have* to use Oracle's client tools to get OLEDB drivers. There are third-party drivers that don't require that you install an entire CD

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did try to grab the same table through a Linked Server, yeah. That also was pretty slow. However, the rest of my extracts are pretty fast, and locally on the Oracle machine, a full table scan takes 4 seconds. Which drivers are you referring to, by the way?

Comment: Check out attunity - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283.  You still need the oracle drivers from oracle, but the component is very fast.  Also note that Blob columns or a table with tons of columns (200+) will really make a dataflow crawl.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz - Those drivers are for SQ Server 2012. We're running 2014. I'm currently sidestepping the issue by having a second box with 2012 on it, but that's less than ideal.

Comment: @SchmitzIT sorry, I should have checked that.  In the past, I have done as you suggested, split the read into different column sets and joined it back together in SQL, which performed very well.  I would also put these into different dataflows each and add a zero to both the Default Buffer Size and Default Max Rows - the memory limit for a buffer in a data flow being 100 MB.  This can help take advantage of available memory on the server.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I will give both a try. I just saw nopw that MS intends to released the Attunity drivers for 2014 soon (tm):
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/917247/when-will-attunity-ssis-connector-support-sql-server-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated Attunity drivers have just been released by Microsoft:

> Hi all, I am pleased to inform you that the Oracle and TeraData connector V3.0 for SQL14
>   SSIS is now available for download!!!!!
>
> Microsoft SSIS Connectors by Attunity Version 3.0 is a minor release.
>   It supports SQL Server 2014 Integration Services and includes bug
>   fixes and support for updated Oracle and Teradata product releases.
>
> For details, please look at the download page.
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44582

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/917247/when-will-attunity-ssis-connector-support-sql-server-2014